# probability of multivariate

Tags: probability, density-function

given a joint cdf
$$ \dfrac{1}{1+e^{-x}}\dfrac{1}{1+e^{-y}}$$
where $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $y\in \mathbb{R}$. Find $P(X \geq 0, Y\geq 0)$. I take the integral and find that it diverges but the notes i have ask me to find an answer (Answer with a fraction.) am i not seeing something? Thanks :)!

Y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case $X,Y$ are independent:

$$F_{XY}=F_X F_Y$$

Thus

$$P(X>0,Y>0)=(1-F_X(0))(1-F_Y(0))=1/4$$

Answer (score 1):

The expression is the cdf, NOT pdf.  You don't integrate.  The probability you want is one - probability that either is negative $=(1-\frac{1}{1+e^0})^2=\frac{1}{4}$.